# C Floating Point to Fixed Point conversion

Tags: c, floating-point, binary, fixed-point

Hi I am trying to make a converter between floating points and fixed point representation without using any library function to do it. So far, the fixed point representation is 16 bits with 10 for the whole number part and 6 for the fractional part. I have been googling and found a possible solution.

```
inline fixed_point_t double_to_fixed(double input)
{
    return (fixed_point_t)(input * (1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS));
}

inline double fixed_to_double(fixed_point_t input)
{
    return ((double)input / (double)(1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS));
}
```

I am struggling to understand the logic behind it. Could someone help explain? And in this case how would the fractional bits be truncated by C down to just 6 bits

Answer (score 2):

How's this:

Sample number = 123.4567890 (base 10)

Still in base 10, convey that same number with "3 fixed point decimals".
To form that value, multiply by 10^3 and drop the remaining decimals.
123.456789 * 1000 => integer == 123457 (or 123_457 where '_' represents the "fixed decimal point".)

This is a base 10 example of the conversion to fixed decimal.

It should be apparent that it can be reversed by dividing by 1000. (The lost precision is lost and cannot be restored.

Now, instead of operating in base 10, do the same thing(s) with a floating point value (`float` or `double`) expressed in base 2.

It's that simple. It's just a matter of degree...

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want a fixed point type using 2 fractional bits. The bit pattern

```
000...0000111  (7 decimal)
```

would then represent the value

```
1 + 0.5 + 0.25 = 1.75
```

Now consider the floating point calculation

```
7 / (1 << 2) = 7 / (2^2) = 7 / 4 = 1.75  (where ^ is power-of)
```

This is exactly how it works.

You get from the **full integer representation** of your fixed point variable to the floating point value by dividing by "2 to the power of NUMBER-OF-FRACTIONAL-BITS"

Comment: thank you for the response! could you help explain the double_to_fixed? when you have time

Answer (score 0):

> to understand the logic behind it.

It is roughly:

`fixed_point_t double_to_fixed(double input)`: multiply `input` by 2<sup>6</sup> and convert to an integer.

`double fixed_to_double(fixed_point_t input)`: convert to a `double` and divide by 2<sup>6</sup>.

---

> found a possible solution.

The following has some weaknesses:

```
inline fixed_point_t double_to_fixed(double input)
{
    return (fixed_point_t)(input * (1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS));
}
```

- "And in this case how would the fractional bits be truncated by C down to just 6 bits" --> Yes, bits in `input` with values less than 2<sup>-6</sup> are silently discarded.  Consider *rounding*.
- Cast of `(fixed_point_t)`, some integer type, risk *undefined behavior* should `input` be much outside the `(fixed_point_t)` range.
- `1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS` is a problem starting when `FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS > 15`.  Use a right-sized type for the `1`.
- With additional code to handle above, perhaps drop the `inline`.

Example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS 6
typedef int16_t fixed_point_t;
#define FIXED_POINT_I_MAX INT16_MAX
#define FIXED_POINT_I_MIN INT16_MIN
// Use the right width type for forming constants.
#define FIXED_POINT_C INT16_C

fixed_point_t double_to_fixed(double input) {
  input *= FIXED_POINT_C(1) << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS;
  // Round ties away from zero by adding 0.5. (Other rounding modes possible.)
  // Works OK when the sum is exact.
  input += (input < 0) ? -0.5 : 0.5;

  // Avoid this form as FIXED_POINT_I_MAX + 1 may wrap
  // if (input >= (FIXED_POINT_I_MAX + 1)) {
  if (input >= (FIXED_POINT_I_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    return FIXED_POINT_I_MAX;
  }

  // Avoid this form as FIXED_POINT_I_MIN - 1 as a FP may be inexact
  // if (input <= (FIXED_POINT_I_MIN - 1)) {
  if (input - FIXED_POINT_I_MIN <= -1) {
    errno = ERANGE;
    return FIXED_POINT_I_MIN;
  }

  return (fixed_point_t)input;
}
```

---

`double fixed_to_double(fixed_point_t input)` is mostly OK.  When the precision of the fixed point (6 in OP's case) exceeds a `double` (53) is that a concern.